# Why is "until" incorrect?

Tags: conditionals, unless, till-until, first-conditional

Choose between:

```
The school will close **unless** it stops snowing soon.
The school will close **until** it stops snowing soon.
```

Just to be clear, "soon" is a given, and it does not refer to the school closing, it refers to the snow stopping.

I was doing this exercise today with my students, and the only difference between the two sentences is "unless/until". In the exercise, people were supposed to choose between unless/until. According to the answer key, the first answer is correct. I know the second answer is wrong, but what is an easy way to explain to someone that it is wrong? For what reasons?

I have an idea but I need to clarify why the second answer is incorrect. Is it because if I say **until**, the focus is more on the long state of being closed? “Until”, by definition means up to a point in time. My preference would be to say “The school will be closed until…”. In that situation, we cannot say the school "will close" until. It sounds strange to me.

Comment: "Until" ... "soon" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is it safe to say we don't ever use "until" with "soon"?

Comment: Doesn't the dictionary tell you difference between 'unless' and 'until'?

Comment: I'm asking for help with explaining something. If I want to go to the dictionary, I can.

Comment: Until means “up to,” so “until 5 o’clock soon” makes no sense.

Comment: @HotLicks ... but "until recently" does??? "until later today" does??? Why does *soon* cause an otherwise adequate criterion to fail and those above do not?

Comment: @PhilSweet "Soon" does not specify a time/date.

Comment: Don’t the sentences just have different meanings? With “unless” the school doesn’t necessarily close (it will stay open if it stops snowing soon) but with “until” (awkward as the sentence feels) it will definitely close and reopen again when it stops snowing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Until](https://www.google.com/search?q=until%20definition)** means

> up to the point in time or the event mentioned

[Oxford Languages]

**[Unless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unless)** means

> except on the condition that

[MW]

To simplify, *until* refers to an actual point in time, even if we don't know when that point is. Unless doesn't refer to time. It refers to a condition being satisfied.

The statement "this condition would need to be satisfied soon" makes sense. The statement "the point in time soon" doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The  illogicality of this construction comes from the fact that the subordinate idea (stops snowing)  is specified as happenig in the future *at an indefinite time*;  this  is made necessary by the conjunction "until", which means "up to the point where this  action is  realized, whatever the time". If, in addition you specify that the point is at a  particular  position in time, that is, near the time of speaking,  then you contradict that this position  in time  has been considered to be indefinite; this is so because "soon" denotes a  point in time that is definite enough.

Let's take a point which is perfectly definite, and  we see even better the nonsense that results.

- The school will close until it stops snowing at noon. (Later addition: *but see **[user Roger Lipscombe's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/595094/why-is-until-incorrect/595098?noredirect=1#comment1496751_595098)***)

Comment: "The school will close until it stops snowing at noon."...

If we _know_ that it's going to stop snowing at noon, that would be OK.

Or, more contrived: it snows every day at noon, but the plough often can't get here until the afternoon. So we'll keep the school closed until the spring -- when it stops snowing at noon.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe That is accessory to the bare question, but worth considering; I  did think  about something such as you mention but thought that I would diverge too much. After all I think it could be explained, so as to  make the exploration of this logical concept more encompassing.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe In your first case I think  a  comma would be  necessary after "snowing" (not the same  grammatical function).

Comment: "I will remain here until Bob arrives to take over on Tuesday." What you wrote sounds good but cannot be right after you think about it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. In your sentence, "Bob arrives to take over on Tuesday" is possibly a usual way of writing the sort of contingecy that we suppose, but in my opinion a comma is necessary after "over". "On Tuesday" cannot be an adverbial modifying "arrives". It corresponds to "until Bob arrives to take over, that  is, on Tuesday". You do not say "Your coat is where you left it in the wardrobe." unless you are talking about a particular place in the wardrobe, which is not  usually what is meant considering the smallness of an average wardrobe. (1/3)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Instead you write and say "Your coat is where you left it**,** in the wardrobe.". In the terminology  of CoGEL, "on Tuesday" is not a predication adjunct but an _apposition conjunct_ (which the comma confirms). Therefore, what you are considering is a use of "until" with a definite point in time: the indefinite "until Bob arrives to take over" (indefinite as  to the point of occurrence in time) is made definite by the addition "on Tuesday". So, you are talking about somethig else, which is related but not relevant to the specific point of the question. (2/3)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.   Please, be careful not  to downvote  before you have acquired the certitude  that you have a point. (3/3)

Comment: There is nothing 'indefinite' about *until* or the phrase/clause it takes as a complement. How about *I will be here until 4pm*!?!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, there is, in this case.  There are two possibilities: definite and indefinite time references. "He works until he is exhausted." (indefinite time)/"He works until  midnight." (definite time).  This  is  not  peculiar to "until" only,   but  "until"  in combination brings that  condition about. There is  a contradiction.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore."I will be here until 4pm": no problem,  it's a definite time.